# AdMob banner is blank with ProGuard enabled

Tags: android, firebase, admob, proguard

I've added the AdMob (320x50 banners) to my project and tested it successfully in debug mode. For production builds I have ProGuard obfuscation enabled and banners disappeared. 
I've tried using these ProGuard rules but it doesn't affect:

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** {
   public *;
}

-keep public class com.google.ads.** {
   public *;
}
```

I initialize AdMob in my Application class like:

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.banner_ad_id));
```

in xml layout I place banner:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

after, I load a banner this way:

```
AdView adMobView = (AdView) bannerLayout.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adMobView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Also, I'm using second ad provider (adtech) and play with their visibility depending on conditions.
Any idea how to make them visible?

Comment: Can you show how you have your banner ad implemented.

Comment: I don't use admob, but I notice [these settings](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/admob/app/proguard-rules.pro#L19-L20) in the sample project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found where was my problem - I shouldn't had set AdView's initial visibility parameter to GONE. Even through I've changed it programmatically to VISIBLE - it did not work in signed apk (still a mystery).