# Admob ads not shown after applied ProGuard rules

Tags: android, admob, apk, proguard, android-proguard

I just finished my app and in final stage before published, but unfortunately I facing problem with Admob ads, I cannot see it after generate the signed apk with ProGuard rules, the ads shown normally when I run app from android studio, I see the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344305/admob-ads-are-not-shown-with-pro-guard) , and I tried all rules provided but didn't working!

**mainActivity ad banner**

```
   public static void mainActivityBanner() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);


        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.

                Log.e("AD ERROR", "error code" + errorCode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
                // covers the screen.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
                // to the app after tapping on an ad.

            }
        });
    }
```

**detailsActivity ads**

```
public static void detailsActivityBanner(){
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);


        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.

                Log.e("AD ERROR", "error code" + errorCode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
                // covers the screen.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
                // to the app after tapping on an ad.

            }
        });
    }

    public static void detailsActivityInterstitial(){
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
                if(clickNumber == 1){
                    interstitialAd.show();
                }else {
                    clickNumber++;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
                clickNumber = 0;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.
                clickNumber = 0;

            }
        });
    }
```

here's my **`proguard-rules.pro file`**

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# You can control the set of applied configuration files using the
# proguardFiles setting in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose
-dontpreverify

-dontnote android.net.http.*
-dontnote org.apache.commons.codec.**
-dontnote org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontnote org.apache.http.**


# Enable Optimization. # Optimization is turned off by default.
-optimizations   code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field
-optimizationpasses 5
-allowaccessmodification


#Disable Optimization
#-dontoptimize
#-dontpreverify

# Remove Log command from code
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log{
 public static *** d(...);
 public static *** i(...);
 public static *** v(...);
}

# -------------------------------------------------
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgent
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference

-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment
-keep public class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment
-keep public class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception

# -------------------------------------------------
-injars libs
-keepattributes *Annotation*, Signature, Exception, EnclosingMethod, InnerClasses
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface

# Keep source file name and line number
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keep class okhttp3.** {*;}
-keep interface okhttp3.** {*;}
-dontwarn okhttp3.**

-keep class okio.** { *; }
-keep interface okio.** { *; }
-dontwarn okio.**

-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.**

-keep class com.activeandroid.** { *; }
-keep class com.activeandroid.**.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.activeandroid.**

-keep class * extends com.activeandroid.Model
-keep class * extends com.activeandroid.serializer.TypeSerializer

-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**

# Dontwarn-----------------------------------------
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn java.lang.management.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn org.json.**


-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}


# -------------------------------------------------
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}


-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}


# Support Library
-keep class android.support.** {*;}
-keep interface android.support.** {*;}


# Needed when building against Marshmallow SDK.
  -dontwarn android.app.Notification


# Retrofit and GSON
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp3.**

-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-dontwarn retrofit2.**

-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.gson.**

-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe.** { *; }
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe.**

-keep public class com.google.gson.** {*;}
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.gson.**

#-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
#-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
#-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {@retrofit2.http.* <methods>;}
-keepclasseswithmembers interface * { @retrofit2.* <methods>;}
-dontwarn com.google.appengine.**
-dontwarn java.nio.file.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform$IOS$MainThreadExecutor


# Volley
-keep class com.android.volley.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.android.volley.**


## Butterknife 8.0
-keep public class * implements butterknife.Unbinder { public <init>(**, android.view.View); }
-keep class butterknife.*
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <methods>; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <fields>; }


# EventBus
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }
# Only required if you use AsyncExecutor
-keepclassmembers class * extends org.greenrobot.eventbus.util.ThrowableFailureEvent {
    <init>(java.lang.Throwable);
}


# OkHttp and Picasso
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**



# Keep line number
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable


# Google Play Admob
    -keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** {
        public *;
    }

    -keep public class com.google.ads.** {
         public *;
    }

    -keep class com.google.ads.** # Don't proguard AdMob classes
    -dontwarn com.google.ads.** # Temporary workaround for v6.2.1. It gives a warning that you can ignore

# Lru Cache
-keep class com.squareup.picasso.LruCache { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.LruCache.**

# Firebase
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.firebase.**

-keepnames class com.shaded.fasterxml.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.shaded.apache.**

-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.**

-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**

-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.**

-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }

-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontnote com.firebase.client.core.GaePlatform

## Android architecture components: Lifecycle
# LifecycleObserver's empty constructor is considered to be unused by proguard
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver {
    <init>(...);
}
# ViewModel's empty constructor is considered to be unused by proguard
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel {
    <init>(...);
}
# keep Lifecycle State and Event enums values
-keepclassmembers class android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle$State { *; }
-keepclassmembers class android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle$Event { *; }
# keep methods annotated with @OnLifecycleEvent even if they seem to be unused
# (Mostly for LiveData.LifecycleBoundObserver.onStateChange(), but who knows)
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.arch.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent *;
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver {
    <init>(...);
}

-keep class * implements android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver {
    <init>(...);
}
-keepclassmembers class android.arch.** { *; }
-keep class android.arch.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.arch.**

-keep class com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView
-dontwarn com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView


#Glide
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
-dontwarn com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.bitmap_recycle.LruBitmapPool
-dontwarn com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.Downsampler
-dontwarn com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.HardwareConfigState

-keep class com.google.**
-dontwarn com.google.**
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe

-keep class org.ocpsoft.prettytime.** {*;}
-dontwarn org.ocpsoft.prettytime.**

-keep class com.androidfung.geoip.**{*;}
-dontwarn com.androidfung.geoip.**

-keep class www.pro_cs_is.com.Utils.**{*;}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AdMob banner is blank with ProGuard enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43552396/admob-banner-is-blank-with-proguard-enabled)

Comment: @unzila it's not blank it's not showing!, also it's not invisible in my XML

Comment: its same thing @dr mido

Comment: have you tried test ads ids with a proguard rule?

Comment: @Vishrut Mavani no I didn't, How to test it?

Comment: @Dr Mido Take test ids from https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads and replace this id with your original ids.

Comment: @Vishrut Mavani the tested unites worked for me, I don't know Why my ads unit not working

Comment: I think it will take time for a load. currently, you app getting no fills. that's why not showing ads.

Comment: yes as @VishrutMavani says in live mode sometimes it takes time to show ads